# Can we run tests in robot framework with comma separated tags?

Tags: testing, jenkins, robotframework

I have tagged my test cases with the feature name.

I have tags like, rest-apis, UI-tests, mysql-tests.

I have enabled Jenkins Job such that we can select tags using checkboxes.

Can I run the tests with the below command?

pybot -L TRACE -i rest-apis,UI-tests /tests/test01.txt

Will this work?

Comment: If you've read the robotframework user's guide and found it confusing on this point, you might want to consider opening a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

comma can not be used as a separator for tags on the command line.
The 2 options you have are:

- repeating the -i option: -i rest-apis -i ui-tests
- using OR operator: -i rest-apisORui-tests

On the second option, not that there is no space and the OR has to be upper case.
Note also that "Tags are free text, but they are normalized so that they are converted to lowercase and all spaces are removed".

Comment: what does it mean then? http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/acceptance-test-mojo.html#includes_cli